# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause ERROR MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1055

I'm just a beginner in using MySQL commands. I've searched this error but their problems are not the same as mine. I'm having a hard time understanding the error where it says `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'japorms.p.item_price' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

I've searched also the meaning of `functionally dependent` but still failed to understand.

here is my query:

```
SELECT
  sum(od.item_qty) as item_qty,
  p.item_name as item_name,
  p.item_price as item_price, 
  od.size as size
from order_details as od, productmaster as p
where p.id = od.item_id 
group by p.item_name
```

If I remove the `p.item_price` and `od.size` from my query, it accepts the `p.item_name` . I wonder why because  `p.item_name` and `p.item_price` are in the same table.

Comment: Which item price and size do you want to show?  Your query implies that you want a sum of quantity for each item.  Then it makes no sense to speak of a single size, you need to think in terms of an aggregate.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: also note that you have applied a `CROSS JOIN` by making `from order_details as od, productmaster as p`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to mention all columns, not being an aggregation function, in group by:

```
SELECT
  SUM(od.item_qty) AS item_qty,
  p.item_name AS item_name,
  p.item_price AS item_price, 
  od.size AS size
FROM order_details AS od, 
JOIN productmaster AS p ON p.id = od.item_id 
GROUP BY p.item_name, p.item_price, od.size
```

in this case, SUM() is such a function, as would be MAX, MIN, COUNT etc

(and changed to an explict written join)

Comment: Thanks! that solved my problem. Does this mean that if you query nonaggregated  columns you must include them in your group by function?

Comment: yes, all of them. In this case consider what happens if you do not group by the size. It would sum all the qty. But which of the sizes would you like to see with it? L? or XL? or even XXXL?

Comment: this query is actually for the cart. so each item has its own size. I just wanted to filter out the duplicate items. instead of showing the same item multiple times, I'll just show a single item and using the SUM() function. I also need to add a condition to also filter the same item but different size. But I it now so thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.  When you use GROUP BY you should specify which column(s) are "grouped by" and which ones are aggregated with a function (eg. SUM, AVG,MIN, MAX, COUNT,...)

```
SELECT
  p.item_name as item_name,
  AVG(p.item_price) as item_price, 
  od.size as size,
  SUM(od.item_qty) as item_qty
from order_details as od
INNER JOIN productmaster as p ON p.id=od.item_id
group by p.item_name, od.size
```